# how to update all the objects in mongoose at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update all the objects in the array in mongoose when the query is fired.

I want to do something like this.

**Initial data**

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "64e460061cbb782e29b8b067" },
  "threadId": { "$oid": "64e460061cbb782e29b8b065" },
  "contactId": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b063" },
  "status": true,
  "conversation": [
    {
      "response": "ABC",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": false
    },
    {
      "response": "DEF",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": false
    },
    {
      "response": "GHI",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": false
    },
    {
      "response": "JKL",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": false
    }
  ],
  "__v": { "$numberInt": "0" }
}
```

**Updated data after query**

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "64e460061cbb782e29b8b067" },
  "threadId": { "$oid": "64e460061cbb782e29b8b065" },
  "contactId": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b063" },
  "status": true,
  "conversation": [
    {
      "response": "ABC",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": true
    },
    {
      "response": "DEF",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": true
    },
    {
      "response": "GHI",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": true
    },
    {
      "response": "JKL",
      "status": false,
      "_id": { "$oid": "64e460051cbb782e29b8b061" },
      "responsed": true
    }
  ],
  "__v": { "$numberInt": "0" }
}
```

I just want to toggle each object's responsed value to true if it is false.

I have written by myself but it is of no use, it just updates the first object rest all the objects remain untouched.

```
await Conversations.updateOne(
  { threadId: "64e460061cbb782e29b8b065", "conversation.responsed": false },
  { "conversation.$.responsed": true }
);
```

The model for above query is as follows:

```
const conversationsSchema = new schema({
    threadId:{
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'threads',
        unique: true
    },
    contactId: {
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'contacts',
        unique: true
    },
    status:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    conversation:[
        {
            response: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            status: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            responsed: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  threadId: ObjectId("64e460061cbb782e29b8b065"),
  "conversation.responsed": false
},
{
  $set: {
    "conversation.$[].responsed": true
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JLhS0ZTVe8-)